# Canvas reduces imagesize of Jpeg, but why?

Tags: html, canvas

When I draw a JPEG-Image to Canvas using `drawImage()` and after that, using `canvas.toDataURL()` to make it saveable local (with right mouseclick), then the saved Jpeg-Image has a reduced filesize about 40%. It is only so, when using Jpeg. PNG, GIF (NON-COMPRESSION-FILES) rises up the size. I thought, if I convert a Image-File to Base64 the size grows up to about 130%. So I think the canvas-element has an own integrated compression-functionality? If so, can I deactivate it?

The Code looks like this:

```
var img = new Image();

img.onload = function () 
{
var width = img.width;
var height = img.height;
context.drawImage(img, 0, 0,width,height);
document.images[0].src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');//<-size = 30,2 KB (30.990 Bytes)
}
img.src = "http://www.roomeffect.de/pageslices/RSB.jpg"; //<-original file size = 58,5 KB (59.930 Bytes)
```

I don't know what the problem is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a problem.  JPG is a lossy format, there's no reason to expect a JPG which is expanded into a bitmap (so you can see it on the screen) to be the same size as a new JPG made from compressing that bitmap again.  If you want the original file to be saved, save the original file.

Comment: "...compressing that bitmap again" ? So does canvas compress that bitmap by its own? base64 is no compression-algo. What disturbs me, is the compressionsize of about 50% thats not good at all.

Comment: @Okyo If you're seeing an image on the screen then it is currently not compressed.  Why is a compression size of 50% not good?  The whole point of compression is to make things smaller.

Comment: yeah thats actually right, what you are saying, but my intention was just to understand the technique behind this issue. anyhow thanx for support!

Answer (score 5):

You can specify the JPEG quality as the second parameter to the toDataURL function. The default quality in Firefox is 0.92 (92%).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCanvasElement

Comment: thanx for quick response, but that doesnt solve the problem, the filesize still gets reduced! Doenst matter wich comp-quality I specify.

Answer (score 3):

This should give you the best results:

```
document.images[0].src = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', 1);
```

Quoted from MDN:

> If the requested type is image/jpeg or image/webp, then the second
>   argument, if it is between 0.0 and 1.0, is treated as indicating image
>   quality.