# What is the default quality for HTML5 Canvas.toDataURL?

Tags: html, html5-canvas

According to mozilla, the second parameter for canvas.toDataURL(1,2) is:

> If the requested type is image/jpeg or image/webp, then the second
>   argument, if it is between 0.0 and 1.0, is treated as indicating image
>   quality; if the second argument is anything else, the default value
>   for image quality is used. Other arguments are ignored.

But I can't find anywhere that tells me what the default value actually is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html), it alludes to the default being browser dependant:

> The second argument, if it is a number in the range 0.0 to 1.0 inclusive, must be treated as the desired quality level. If it is not a number or is outside that range, the **user agent** must use **its** default value, as if the argument had been omitted.

**Edit:** According to [one user](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8371510/577306) the default for Firefox is 0.92.

> You can specify the JPEG quality as the second parameter to the toDataURL function. The default quality in Firefox is 0.92 (92%).

And according to this [webkit bug report](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49365#c6) Chrome uses the same.

> ...Adds a libjpeg-based image encoder for Skia bitmaps.  Default encoding quality
>               is 92 to match Mozilla...

Answer (score 0):

Tested saving canvas content with `.webp` in chrome and edge with same result showing the quality parameter default value to be 0.8.

Here are results with quality on the left:

> default -> 313.65 kB
> 1 -> 8.29 MB
> 0.9 -> 0.98 MB
> 0.8 -> 313.65 kB
> 0.7 -> 200.63 kB
> 0.6 -> 160.19 kB
> 0.5 -> 130.57 kB
> 0.4 -> 109.31 kB
> 0.3 -> 91.17 kB
> 0.2 -> 75.09 kB
> 0.1 -> 67.78 kB
> 0 -> 48.71 kB

This makes me think that quality parameter may be optimized for biggest decrease in weight and highest image quality and can be different for other image types.